# How an airlock works?

Tags: pressure, air

From wikipedia:

> Before opening either door, the air pressure of the airlock—the space between the doors—is equalized with that of the environment beyond the next door to open

Anyone knows how this work? What the mechanism make possible "equalize" the air pressure between the doors? For example, in the ISS (International Space Station).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How an airlock works?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22973/how-an-airlock-works)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

each "end" of the airlock has a valve in it which, when opened, allows the pressure between the inside of the airlock chamber and the pressure inside the adjacent chamber to equalize. Once this is done, the equalizing valve is shut and then the door to the adjacent chamber can safely be opened.

Comment: Do they just vent the gas into space?

Comment: @joojaa Yes, exactly.

Comment: @EricShain Seems wasteful. But that's certainly the fast way to go about things. But i suppose having a pump to recover the atmosphere may not be cost efficient.

Comment: @joojaa Pumps are heavy. It’s about the cost of lifting mass to orbit.

Comment: @EricShain Please provide a source of your info, and to which airlocks it applies. The systems vary. Reduced pressure soaks (called camping out) are used to prevent the bends. I believe in some units this is pumped down and recovered, but haven't found a source.

Comment: @PhilSweet I was referring specifically to the international space station. I don't have a source so its possible I'm wrong but I kind of doubt it. There isn't much chance of getting the bends in space since an astronaut would be at about the same pressure in their spacesuit as they would in the space station.

Comment: @EricShain not true, the EMU operates at 5psi. 24 hour soaks to blow off nitrogen are the norm. This can be reduced at the expense of a longer prebreath of pure O2 via mask or in the suit prior to eva.